# Get Client IP address on Worklight Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

We are developing hybrid application using WL6.2. In our adapter we have this code:

```
var request = WL.Server.getClientRequest(); 
var IPAddress = request.getHeader('X-Archieved-Client-IP');
if(IPAddress == null || IPAddress == undefined || IPAddress == "") {
    IPAddress = request.getHeader('X-Archieved-Client-IP');
}
if(IPAddress == null || IPAddress == undefined || IPAddress == "") {
    IPAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
}
if(IPAddress == null || IPAddress == undefined || IPAddress == "") {
    //This will never happen, only for precaution.
    IPAddress = "192.168.1.1";
}

commonParams.originatingIp = (IPAddress)?IPAddress:request.getRemoteAddr();
```

I'm not able to get the client IP address on the adapter, and our web services only see one IP address which is the Data power IP.And In the logs I see our Data power IP address as "orginatingIP". which means `"getRemoteAddr()"` is being executed.

```
<OriginatingIP>DataPowerIP</OriginatingIP>
```

If I kept only this part of code:

```
var request = WL.Server.getClientRequest(); 
var IPAddress = request.getHeader('X-Archieved-Client-IP');
commonParams.originatingIp = IPAddress;
```

I'm getting value as "null".

```
<OriginatingIP>null</OriginatingIP>
```

I tried also this solution "[IBM Worklight 6 - How would i get client IP address on adapter side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720621/ibm-worklight-6-how-would-i-get-client-ip-address-on-adapter-side)" also didn't work.

any suggestions please? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will update your adapter as follow

```
var request = WL.Server.getClientRequest(); 

var ipAddress = request.getHeader('x-client-ip');

switch(ipAddress){
  case "":
  case null:
  case undefined:
    //This will never happen, only for precaution.
    ipAddress = "192.168.1.1";
  break;
}
```

From this post https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/10123/how-do-you-get-the-original-ip-doing-the-request-to-your-bluemix-app.html it looks like you should use `x-client-ip` instead of using `X-Archieved-Client-IP`

Answer (score 0):

This Thread worked for me.

[what is the right way to get request's ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350318/what-is-the-right-way-to-get-requests-ip)

Try **request.getRemoteAddr()**